# Protostuff serialized bytecode on Android cannot be deserialized on PC

Tags: java, android, serialization, protostuff

When I try to deserialize my serialized model on PC, I get the strange error seen at the bottom. 
Deserializing works on Android, as does the case where I serialize the same model on PC and deserialize it on PC. 
So this appears to be an interoperability problem.

What can I do to ensure it serializes the same way?

My model that has to be serialized has the following POJOS and collections:

```
ExplicitIdStrategy.Registry reg = new ExplicitIdStrategy.Registry();
    reg.registerPojo(EntityData.class, 1);
    reg.registerPojo(ProbabilityModel.class, 2);
    reg.registerPojo(ProbabilityModelEntryList.class, 3);
    reg.registerCollection(CollectionSchema.MessageFactories.valueOf("ArrayList"), 4);
    reg.registerMap(MapSchema.MessageFactories.valueOf("HashMap"), 5);
    reg.registerEnum(ProbabilityModel.OtherCounted.class, 6);
    reg.registerCollection(CollectionSchema.MessageFactories.valueOf("HashSet"), 7);
```

It seems the Map is serialized differently on Android and on a Windows PC. I have no deep knowledge of protostuff, but it is fairly strange that it depends on operating systems when using operating system independent JAVA...

```
com.dyuproject.protostuff.ProtostuffException: The map was incorrectly serialized.
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.MapSchema.mergeFrom(MapSchema.java:316)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.MapSchema.mergeFrom(MapSchema.java:31)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.GraphCodedInput.mergeFrom(GraphCodedInput.java:153)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.CodedInput.mergeObjectEncodedAsGroup(CodedInput.java:271)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.CodedInput.mergeObject(CodedInput.java:239)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.GraphCodedInput.mergeObject(GraphCodedInput.java:108)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.runtime.RuntimeMapFieldFactory$5.mergeFrom(RuntimeMapFieldFactory.java:463)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.runtime.MappedSchema.mergeFrom(MappedSchema.java:188)
    at com.dyuproject.protostuff.GraphIOUtil.mergeFrom(GraphIOUtil.java:76)
    at com.android.diabetesmodel.ModelEntity.deserialize(ModelEntity.java:185)
    at com.android.diabetesmodel.test.VersionManagerEntityTest.from1to2Upgrade(VersionManagerEntityTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you serialize and deserialize with the same Protostuff JVM option **protostuff.runtime.collection_schema_on_repeated_fields**?

Comment: I did use the exact same code on PC and on ANDROID. IS there some nasty System dependent flag hidden somewhere? I get the runtimescheme with the exact same parameters. 

private static Schema getSchema() {
return RuntimeSchema.getSchema(EntityData.class,ModelEntity.mSerialStrategy);
 }

Comment: Do you use the @Tag annotation in your POJOs? This could also be caused by an ordering issue. According to the protostuff website: "Note that the order is not guaranteed on some (non-sun) vms (especially dalvik)."